# How to access Time Machine without the access password?

Tags: time-machine, password

I have an older 2TB Apple Time Machine with years of kids photos.

Unfortunately, my wife cannot remember the passcode to get in.  We are at a loss as we have tried every password we can think of. We really don't want to loose all these kids pics!

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use AirPort Utility to log in to the base station and reset the disk sharing password.

If you can't remember that password, the button on the back of the unit can reset that password to the default value of "private".